# Как реализовать очередь действий?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, очередь-задач

У меня есть 1 поток, который постоянно получает данные из `OutputStream`, а есть 2 поток, который должен получать задачи от первого и по очереди их выполнять, и подчёркиваю, это очень важно, **ПО ОЧЕРЕДИ**! А не получил задачи и выполняет их в разнобой.

Вот тут я и не могу определиться, что мне тут лучше использовать:

- Думал в строну пула потоков, но с ним проблемы могут возникнуть, да и нету нужды сразу несколько задач выполнять одновременно (хотя не знаю, может и имеет смысл, главное, чтобы очерёдность сохранялась).
- Также почитал про AWT, похоже данная реализация мне подходит, там есть 1 фоновый поток, все задачи выполняются последовательно, но тоже свои косяки.
- Также почитал про Очередь действий, всё выполняется последовательно, но уже в несколько потоков, такой вариант в принципе лучше всего.

Вот и не знаю, куда двигать лучше, решил спросить совету высших умов. Как думаете, каким путём пойти? Есть ли готовая реализация Очереди действий в java или Android? Если есть, то посоветуйте источники. Также хотелось бы иметь возможность прервать работу очереди задач и обнулить всю информацию в ней, думаю, если такого решения нету, то буду ваять сам. Заранее спасибо.

Всю инфу черпал на хабре и вот [этой хорошей статье](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp0730/).

Answer (score 2):

`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`
и execute() туда задачи от первого потока.
по умолчанию очередь задач будет неограниченой, если хочется чтоб было ограничение - можно тоже покрутить, передав свою `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`.

Comment: Насколько я знаю нечто подобное реализовано в Android в IntentService, я правильно понял?

Comment: К сожалению про андроид ничего не могу сказать, на яве я бы использовал однопоточный экзекутор.

Comment: Но судя по документации - да. Это именно то что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую. P.S. : Какой умник минусы кидает?

Comment: Вполне заслуженно, мой ответ не совсем по теме :)

Comment: Не скажите, а вопрос чем людям не понравился?

Comment: думаю с оформлением что-нибудь не так.

Answer (score 2):

Модная нынче тема - RxJava, хорошо справляется с синхронизацией разных запросов, причем потоки могут быть самые разные.

Answer (score 1):

Готовая реализация очереди в андроид это [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Выполняется в фоновом потоке, и одновременно только одна задача и в порядке очереди. Один интент - одна задача.

Ну или как вариант использовать AsyncTask и [SERIAL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR):

```
 task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: Спасибо, я принципе знал о IntentService, но не был в курсе точной работы её потоков, а именно очерёдности выполнения

Comment: Дописал про AsyncTask

Comment: Не, AsyncTask - гнилая тема, с ним есть проблемы. Он не гарантирует завершения потока, а вот IntentService гарантирует

Comment: Не гарантирует завершение потока?

Comment: Да, вам не послышалось, есть случаи, что поток может прерваться не закончив работу

Comment: Ну если вы сделаете `cancel(true)` то поток прервется, это нормально. Но с таким же успехом может прерваться любой поток.

Comment: А я и не про это. Я про то, что поток может прерваться не по нашей инициативе, а по инициативе системы